# C# Identify Which Property Caused a Null Reference Exceptions in Object Initialization in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

Let's say I am a initializing a new object at once that has many properties. One of them causes a null reference exception, but when you use the debugger it passes through the entire code initialization block at once. Is there any easy way to find which property caused the error. Note that the object properties maybe  many types so some of the types are allowed to be null.

ex object initalization

```
var obj = new Obj{
prop1 = x,
prop2 = y,
prop3 = f,
prop4 = r,
prop5 = h,
prop6 = k,
prop7 = w,
prop8 = l,
prop8 = m,
prop9 = e,
prop10 = a 
};
```

One of these properties caused the null reference exception but you don't know which and the debugger passed through the entire block at once. Is there a method to identify this with visual studio?

Comment: Properties don't cause NREs, unless they contain logic in the setter. Is it actually one of your `x`, `y`, `f`, ... accesses that's actually a null dereference (so you actually use `x.Foo`)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is one of the most annoying things about property initialization. You could replace it (even temporarily) with one-by-one property assignments (assuming these are get;set; and not get;init; properties) .

Comment: @CodeCaster this is just example object, many of the object I'm working with might contain 50+ properties and nested objects

Comment: Yeah so your x, y, f are simplified examples that don't really reproduce your issue?

Comment: well the issue is the same could occur in this exact code block as well, if they are null properties. This is a general issue, that we face when developing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on the assignment to `obj` and open the Locals window. Observe the values of the variables that you are assigning to the properties of `obj`. Aside from that, Visual Studio itself doesn't have much built-in to help you in this regard (that I'm aware of or can recall at the moment) aside from tooltips.

This is the biggest drawback of object and list initializers. If you're assigning to lots of properties, the exception is thrown on the first line of the initialization block, as you've observed. It's *incredibly* annoying, and can make things difficult to track down.

If you're fortunate enough to be using a fairly advanced refactoring addon (like Resharper or CodeRush), there should be a refactoring to convert an object initializer into direct property assignments and back again. This would allow you to convert the object initializer into property assignments, debug the code so you can isolate the problem statement quickly, resolve it, and then convert the code back into an object initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider inspecting your browser and take note of which property is empty.
My advise

Comment: Not following how this is an answer to the question..